# Petapoco doing something when Update is performed

Tags: asp.net, .net, petapoco

I have to perform some operation whenever the `Upload()` **Petapoco** method is called... The response could be to override it inheriting the Database class but unfortunately `Upload()` is private... Is there anybody with the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**: Fork PetaPoco (it's open source) and change the method to do what you want.

**Suggested alternative solution**: Use an extension method that execute the Update, and then do what you want.

```
    // Example
    public static void SaveAndLog(this PetaPoco.Database db, object rec) {
        bool IsNew = db.IsNew(rec);
        db.Save(rec);
        db.Log(rec, (IsNew ? "Creó" : "Editó"));
    }
```

Why? Because it's better to use the original package and get all the updates without worring about merges, and also, you have the freedom to use the original method when suited.